# How efficient is Zinc Acetate as an Oxygen absorber?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, redox

I used to work in a microbiology lab and they used zinc acetate as O2 absorber for the anaerobic chamber. Was this an efficient way to scrub O2 from the air? I am asking because I want to make an N2 gas source by removing the oxygen from airflow. I only need to be able to produce at most 500 ccm of 99% N2. Is there something else I should consider?

Comment: I don't see any way for this compound to absorb oxygen, at all...

Comment: Just look up commercial O2 scrubbers, e.g. https://www.chromres.com/blog/the-fundamentals-of-oxygen-scrubbing  BTW, it is probably more economical to use compressed N2 or liquid N2, only using a scrubber to remove the last fraction of a percent of O2 that enters the system.

Comment: @Mithoron That was what they told me it was, they said it was zinc acetate dissolved in mineral oil, and the air was bubbled through it using an air pump and stone for a fish tank. The O2 in the chamber stayed below 0.5% at all times.

Comment: @DrMoishe Pippik I am trying to avoid using compressed sources and I do not have easy access to liquid N2. Thank you for the link though.